# Inline Word-Break of Text with Image

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to place text on the right side of an image.  I need the text to "break" without going beneath the image.

The "break" in the text is the result of the intentionally confined width.

I've made a [JSFiddle of what I'm trying to do](https://jsfiddle.net/Mystagogue/gfdwpxfs/), but it is broken.  Some of the text is to the right of the image, which is correct, and the rest is below the image, which is incorrect.

What can I do to fix this?  I'm free to use most any markup or styling; I am not restricted to the `div` elements in my example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified the code for you. I hope it helps.

```html
<body style="width: 280px">

<img style="float: left;margin-right:20px;" src="https://v.cdn.vine.co/r/avatars/23E08B47E61293643069115232256_4965b3761ec.5.0.jpg?versionId=bDYNR_haJsXGejeKLJtX1QK8hP4cJUW5" />
<div style="word-wrap:break-word">Jonathan-Paul Montgomery-Benson</div>

</body>
```

The better way to code it is to avoid inline style. Here is the snippet for this:

```css
body {
      width: 280px;
  }
  img {
      float: left;
      margin-right: 20px;
  }
  .break {
      word-wrap: break-word;
  }
```

```html
<body>

<img src="https://v.cdn.vine.co/r/avatars/23E08B47E61293643069115232256_4965b3761ec.5.0.jpg?versionId=bDYNR_haJsXGejeKLJtX1QK8hP4cJUW5" />
<div class="break">Jonathan-Paul Montgomery-Benson</div>

</body>
```

Comment: When the <body> width is restored to 280px, the text actually behaves the way I want; even the overflow:hidden becomes unnecessary!  In short, the only problem with my example is that I used "display:inline".  By removing that one attribute, it achieves my goal.

Comment: You want to text below image or on right side of image where I have added it?

Comment: Text remains on right side even if you reduce the body width to 280px. Check the modified code

Answer (score 0):

I have done some changes in the markup. Hope this will help.

```css
.block {
  display: flex;
  width: 280px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="block"><img src="https://v.cdn.vine.co/r/avatars/23E08B47E61293643069115232256_4965b3761ec.5.0.jpg?versionId=bDYNR_haJsXGejeKLJtX1QK8hP4cJUW5" />
    <div>Jonathan-Paul Montgomery-Benson</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following markup to achieve this.

```css
.row{width:280px;}
.row:after{clear:both; content:""; display:block;}
.img-col{width:40%; float:left;}
.img-col img{width:100%; height:auto;}
.des-col{width:57%; float:right;}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="img-col">
    <img  src="https://v.cdn.vine.co/r/avatars/23E08B47E61293643069115232256_4965b3761ec.5.0.jpg?versionId=bDYNR_haJsXGejeKLJtX1QK8hP4cJUW5" />
  </div>
  
  <div class="des-col">Jonathan-Paul Montgomery-Benson</div>

</div>
```

You can set the ".img-col" width according to your design.

Comment: When the <body> width is set to the original 280px, the text appears underneath the image.  The 280px width is a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it it like this.Hope this helps.

```css
.class-txt{
  display: inline;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    width: 60%;
    position: relative;
    
    float: left;
}
.img-class{
  width : 40%;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<body style="width: 280px">

<img class='img-class'  src="https://v.cdn.vine.co/r/avatars/23E08B47E61293643069115232256_4965b3761ec.5.0.jpg?versionId=bDYNR_haJsXGejeKLJtX1QK8hP4cJUW5" />
<div class="class-txt" style="display:inline; word-wrap: break-word;">Jonathan-Paul Montgomery-Bensononathan-Paul Montgomery-Benson onathan-Paul Montgomery-Benson onathan-Paul Montgomery-Benson onathan-Paul Montgomery-Benson onathan-Paul Montgomery-Benson</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `display:flex;` css style property

```html
<body style="width: 280px">

<img style="float: left;margin-right:20px;" src="https://v.cdn.vine.co/r/avatars/23E08B47E61293643069115232256_4965b3761ec.5.0.jpg?versionId=bDYNR_haJsXGejeKLJtX1QK8hP4cJUW5" />
<div style="display:flex;">Jonathan-Paul Montgomery-Benson Jonathan-Paul Montgomery-Benson </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
 <div style="display:inline-flex; word-wrap: break-word;">
    <img style="float: left;" src="https://v.cdn.vine.co/r/avatars  /23E08B47E61293643069115232256_4965b3761ec.5.0.jpg?versionId=bDYNR_haJsXGejeKLJtX1QK8hP4cJUW5" />
 <div>Jonathan-Paul Montgomery-Benson</div>
</div>
</body>
```